# List&Label 16: Stop header of table to be copied on new page

Tags: forms, report, reporting, listlabel

I have a combit List & Label 16 form in which i have a reportcontainer with a table.

The table is pretty simple and looks basically like this:

```
Header
-------------------------------------
Row 1 Column 1     |   Row 1 Column 2
Row 2 Column 1     |   Row 2 Column 2
...
```

Now when there are too many rows to fit on one page, the table continues on a new page and the **header gets copied!**

How can I prevent the header to be copied on the new page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out how to do it:

- Open the detail menu of the table
- Select "Table Header"
- Set the condition for visibility to `FirstHeaderThisTable`